# Integral Over a two dimensional surface in 4 space

Tags: special-relativity, differential-geometry

I am reading Landau and Lifshitz's book *The Classical Theory of Fields*. They make the following statement in the book. [image]

I am interested in trying to show that $df_{ik}df^{*ik}=0.$ I intuitively see why it is true, but I can not figure out how to show that it is true just through manipulating the expression $\frac{1}{2}e^{ik\ell m}df_{\ell m}df_{ik}$. Can somebody show me how to manipulate that equation to show that it is $0$?